# Generate PDF file in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I would like to generate PDF file in JavaFX. For example I would like to print the scene in PDF file. Is this possible without external library?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible without using an external library. Though, creating an image file is possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible without an external library. I do as ItachiUchiha suggests: convert the `AnchorPane` into an image via `snapshot` and then print out the image I created.